# How do you know monerod has synced?

Tags: monerod, synchronization, stagenet

I’ve a `monerod` on stagenet. How can I know it’s synced the blockchain?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you know `monerod` has synced?

Multiple different ways:

- If running interactively in a console, you'll see a message when synchronized or you can run `status` at any time which shows the same.
- You can also run `monerod status` in another shell to get the same message.
- You can call the daemon's RPC method [get_info](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info) which has a property `synchronized` in the response. E.g.

  ```
  curl http://127.0.0.1:38081/json_rpc -d \
    '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"get_info"}'

  {
    "id": "0",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
      ...
      "synchronized": true,
      ...
    }
  }
  ```
- You could watch the log file.

> I’ve a `monerod` on stagenet.

Which network is irrelevant. All the above work, the only caveat with the RPC option is making sure you use the correct port number (18081 for mainnet, 28081 for testnet and 38081 for stagenet).